# How to clear hash from url in chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, url-rewriting, scriptmanager

I am working with location.hash in url because I need to add some additional data at the url end (like `...com/page#something`).
But after that I move to some other page that shouldn't have hash in url and somehow hash apper in that url (`home.com#hash`).
This happens only in chrome, firefox is fine.
I wan't to on each pageLoad clear hash if there is some.
I have tried with this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "noHash", "window.location.hash = ' ';", true);
```

But this leaves '#' at the url end only in chrome.
Any idea how to remove this?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>try this</kbd>

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "noHash", "if (window.location.indexOf('#')>-1) window.location = window.location.hash.split('#')[0];", true);
```

Comment: I put this in page load but somehow it's make infinite loop.

Comment: @1110 you must have a problem somewhere else. upload a jsfiddle or something